# Select specific username and display something in his profile

Tags: php, mysql

```
 <?php
    if(!isset($_POST['searchIto'])){
}
       $search_sql="SELECT status FROM users WHERE id=id";
       $search_query=mysql_query($search_sql);

   if(mysql_num_rows($search_query)!=null){

       $search_rs=mysql_fetch_assoc($search_query);
}

 if(mysql_num_rows($search_query)!=null){

  do{?>

   <span>Status:&nbsp;</span><?php echo $search_rs['status'];?><br>

<?php

     }while($search_rs=mysql_fetch_assoc($search_query));
}

else{
    echo "No results found";
}
?>
```

this code echo all the status of all registered, i only want to display the status of specific user that is logged in. like if user1 has status value of 1 display 1 and user2 has status value of 2 display 2

Comment: Can you give us the structure of your table ?

Comment: id=id | username=user_name | status=status @Heru-Luin

Comment: `if(!isset($_POST['searchIto'])){
}`

this code does not do anything, it may help you find what's wrong

Comment: yeah its useless, i deleted it and the query still worked. but i only want to display the status value of specific user not all users, i think it's on $search_sql, @Heru-Luin

Comment: it's relatively easy to do, a simple google search will give you a number of tutorials to show user specific content.

Comment: i can't find anything, can you give me the keyword that I need to search? thanks @Ashesh

Comment: You should take clues from a registration, login system using php and mysql.

Answer (score 0):

After few debugging, I found a solution:

```
 <?php

$startNa = $_SESSION['user_id'];
$search_sql="SELECT status FROM users WHERE id='$startNa'";
$search_query=mysql_query($search_sql);

  if(mysql_num_rows($search_query)!=null){
   $search_rs=mysql_fetch_assoc($search_query);
}
  if(mysql_num_rows($search_query)!=null){
     do{?>
<span>Status:&nbsp;</span><?php echo $search_rs['status'];?><br>

<?php
       }while($search_rs=mysql_fetch_assoc($search_query));
}
else{

echo "No results found";
}
?>
```

I just add $_SESSION[]; 
btw thanks for the answers, you helped me a lot